# The Sign of the Strain Tensor Determinant and What it Means

Tags: linear-algebra, continuum-mechanics, stress-strain

**Background**

I'm currently working my way through Milton's and Cherkaev's, "[Which Elasticity Tensors Are Realizable?](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Andrej-Cherkaev/publication/249505453_Which_Elasticity_Tensors_are_Realizable/links/0c960530ebc8f6a0ad000000/Which-Elasticity-Tensors-are-Realizable.pdf)" as part of my research. I come from an electrical engineering background so I'd say my linear algebra is adequate as an engineer, but I've been teaching myself mechanical engineering, continuum mechanics, etc. this past year.

Milton goes through great efforts in the beginning of Section $2$ to talk about the extremal materials in terms of the eigenvalues of the elasticity matrix, but then shifts to discussing the eigenvalues/vectors of the strain tensor in Section $2.1$. He then says that for a strain tensor
$$
\epsilon = -c \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}
$$
the "determinant is non-negative," which is a typo because the determinant is definitely negative given $det(kA) = k^ndet(A)$ for $k \in \mathbb{R}$ and  $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$.

Besides the typo, he emphasizes that the sign of the strain tensor determinant is the "significant feature" and then begins a discussion about finding a material that supports a strain with a positive determinant.

**My question is**: What is the physical insight on the impact of the sign of the strain tensor's determinant and why is it the "significant feature" for Milton? I have a grasp on what a negative determinant means in general (i.e. changing the orientation), but all physical intuition goes out the window here when Milton emphasizes this feature. What is it about pure shear strain that "flips" the orientation and what orientation am I even talking about?

**P.S.** I've also got about a million other questions on this same paper if anyone has the time to talk directly or is willing to correspond with me about this.

Comment: Be careful with the notation and terminology. He is talking abut the "elasticity tensor" (which personally I would call the compliance tensor) but then represents a special case of a that 4th-order tensor as a 3x3 matrix. At that point I lost the will to disentangle every detail of the paper.

Comment: @alephzero, this tensor is commonly termed "stiffness tensor", the compliance tensor is the inverse of this one. That is the one that maps stresses to strains. Also, In section 2.1 the tensor that the OP is referring to is the strain tensor and not the stiffness tensor.

Comment: @DanielRevier, there are several mechanicians that hang on Twitter (myself included) if you want to discuss about things.

Comment: @nicoguaro Thanks for the invitation. I found you on Twitter today so if you can recommend some others to follow I'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

We know that the deformation gradient must have a positive determinant because material cannot pass through itself. The determinant equals the ratio of the
deformed to the undeformed infinitesimal volume elements. If its determinant is zero, then a volume (or area) has collapsed to zero, which is also unphysical. In terms of strain, however, the significance may be different. I will take a look tomorrow if I have time.

Answer (score 1):

It's been a while since I read that paper, but taking a look at it I would say that the typo is not saying "non-negative" but in saying "determinant". I suppose that the authors meant to say "trace" instead.

Let me explain why. As mentioned in another answer, the determinant of the deformation gradient represents the change in volume and it should be non-negative.

We can express the new volume differential as

$$dV' = dV(1 + \epsilon_1)(1 + \epsilon_2)(1 + \epsilon_3)\, ,$$

where $\epsilon_i$ are the eigenvalues of the strain tensor. If we neglect higher-order terms it translates to

$$dV' = dV(1 + \epsilon_1 +  \epsilon_2 + \epsilon_3)\, ,$$

and $\epsilon_1 + \epsilon_2 + \epsilon_3$ represents the relative change of volume

$$\frac{dV' - dV}{dV}\, ,$$

and it is equal to the trace of the tensor.

Also, note that in the previous sentence the authors list the eigenvalues of the tensor properly, that is another indicator.

Comment: I would be inclined to agree with you on the "determinant" vs "trace" typo, but they use the word determinant several times throughout the paper. Eq. 2.5 has "zero determinant". After discussing the negative determinant they want to find "unimodal materials with easy strains having positive determinant."

Comment: To imagine they used the wrong word repeatedly throughout the paper...I really hope for my own research sake they weren't that sloppy. :/

Comment: @DanielRevier, but eq. 2.5, indeed has zero determinant. Furthermore, it is not the strain tensor but the stress tensor. There is a direction with no stresses.

Comment: In eq. 2.9 they do refer to the determinant. So yes, I think that there is a typo on the specific part that you posted in the question and after that determinant seems to be OK. Note that at the end what you want is to find the parameters of the stiffness tensor. So, you are transforming a specific stress state to a specific strain state; that's the job of the compliance/stiffness tensor.